# Everywhere discontinuous bijections, do they exist?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I started to do some research on an unanswered highly upvoted question from this site and on a piece of paper I wrote:

> Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at every point and $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$ and $f$ is bijection

...and I stopped writing. Although I did not settle that question, I realized that I supposed that there (and here) exist some functions with properties mentioned above, and started to do a research without really knowing are there such functions?

So, in order to not to discuss and think about functions that I even do not know do they exist, I decided to ask you:

> Let $f$ be an everywhere discontinuous (meaning, discontinuous at every point) bijection that maps $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$. Do such functions exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational and $x+1$ if $x$ is irrational gives such a  function.

Comment: Very simple answer.

Comment: Do you have an example if we suppose that we also have $f(x) \neq x$ everywhere?

Comment: Well, what about $x+1$ for rationals and $x+2$ for irrationals?

Comment: Yes. I realized that we have when I added a comment, but did not want to delete a comment. What if we also have that for every interval $I$ that $I$ and $f(I)$ are disjoint?

Comment: What type of intervals are you talking about? If $I=(-\infty,\infty)$ then $I$ and $f(I)$ cannot be disjoint.

Comment: Finite intervals, of course.

Comment: No such function c an exist. If $n$ is  a large positive integer then $0$ and $f^{-1}(0)$ both belong to $(-n,n)$ so $0 \in (-n,n)\cap f(-n,n)$.

Comment: If my answer is acceptable you can consider approving it. @AnteP.